# Parsing and converting 4Test to Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, interpreter

I want to convert 4Test scripts to Perl. I have been using the Parse::RecDescent in Perl, but am still overwhelmed at the task. Here is an example.

An example of 4Test is something like:

```
ParseSMSPlans (STRING sDir)
{
STRING sFile;
STRING sDirSMSPlan = sDir + "sms_plans\";
STRING sDirPlan = sDir + "plan\";
STRING sDirDeal = sDir + "deal\";
STRING sDirProduct = sDir + "product\";
STRING sLine, sType, sName;
HFILE hIn;
FILEINFO fiFile;
LIST OF FILEINFO lfInfo = SYS_GetDirContents (sDirSMSPlan);
       ...
}
```

...
This is my Parse::RecDescent grammar

```
my $grammar = q{

#-----------------identifiers and datatypes-------------------#

    identifier : /[a-z]\w+/
    binops : '+' | '-' | '/' | '*' | '%' | '**'
    lbinops: '!' | '<' | '>' | '>='| '<='| '&&'| '||' | '=='
    integer: /\d+/ {print "hello $item[-1]" if $::debugging;}
    number : /(\d+|\d*\.\d+)/ {print "hello $item[-1]" if $::debugging;}
    string : /"(([^"]*)(\\")?)*"/
    operation : number binops number operation(s?)
    datatype : /[a-zA-Z]\w*/
    definition : datatype expression(s) #{print "hello $item[-1]" if $::debugging;}
                |datatype expression(s) "=" expression(s) #{print "hello $item[-1] = $item[-2]" if $::debugging;}
    statement : ifexp | elsexp | elseifexp |forexp | feachexp | whexp | swcexp


#------------------Expressed Values-----------------------------#
    program : expression
    expression :  number {print $item[1] if $::debugging}
                | integer
                | assignment
                | operation
                | identifier binops expression
                | number binops expression

#------------------Conditionals---------------------------------------#

    ifexp  : 'if' '(' expression(s) ')' '{' expression(s) '}' elsexp(?)
    elsexp : 'else' '{' expression(s) '}'
    elseifexp: 'else' 'if' '(' expression(s) ')' '{' expression(s) '}'
    forexp : 'for' '(' expression ';' expression ';' expression ')' '{' expression(s)  }'
           | 'for' assignment 'to' number expression(s) | 'for' assignment 'to' number '{' expression(s) '}'
    feachexp : 'for each' expression 'in' expression '{' expression(s) '}'
    whexp  : 'while' '(' expression ')' '{' expression(s) '}'
    casest : 'case' expression(s /,/) ':'
    swcexp : 'switch' identifier '{' casest(s) '}' expression(s) 'default'
    assignment : identifier(s) '=' expression
};
```

So, I'm looking at adding "$" to every variable name, and chopping
datatypes. For the most part my grammar works, though I have fully
tested it yet, but only because Parse::RecDescent has been a bit
tricky for me to understand and, I'm not really sure if it's the best
way to complete my task...or the fastest, for that matter.

My main concern is whether or not anyone feels that PRD can handle what
I'm asking it to do or will simple(complex) regex(s) suffice? I would
appreciate any help anyone could offer on this.

Comment: Have you looked at Regexp::Grammars?

Comment: Do you need a full interpreter for 4test or just to convert a few scripts?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you simplify your 4Test scripts by replacing all operator expressions with subroutine calls.  You would then still be able to run them as 4Test scripts and thus prove that they worked, but you would greatly simplify the parsing problem - operator expressions are much more difficult to parse than straight procedure calls.  Taken to the limit, this process will produce 4Test scripts which can almost be run directly by Perl+some replacement routines for 4Test functions.